# iOS App Crashing Before Running

Tags: iphone, xcode, crash

I was working on my app and it was running fine. I made some small changes to the code (which I have since undone to test if they were to blame) and it's started crashing on running. It appears to be crashing before even running my code or loading view in the thread `com.apple.main-thread`

The debugger breaks here

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
0x3619a324:  mov    r12, #328
0x3619a328:  svc    #128
0x3619a32c:  blo    0x3619a344               ; __pthread_kill + 32
0x3619a330:  ldr    r12, [pc, #4]
0x3619a334:  ldr    r12, [pc, r12]
0x3619a338:  b      0x3619a340               ; __pthread_kill + 28
0x3619a33c:  stceq  p12, c9, [lr, #896]
0x3619a340:  bx     r12                      
0x3619a344:  bx     lr
```

At the line

```
0x3619a32c:  blo    0x3619a344               ; __pthread_kill + 32
```

I thought it might be something in the code I changed I missed so I pulled a version from a month ago backed up off-site which is the IDENTICAL code that is in use for the current version on App Store but it crashes at the same place.

It must be something to do with the iPhone itself as both versions of the code run fine in iPhone Simulator.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace instead of the disassembly. It's impossible to see with what you see here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried rebooting your iPhone? I find that sometimes you need to do that when when you get weird crashes. Not much of a real answer, but you didn't mention that you rebooted the device or not.

Comment: Sometimes it's the simple things. Rebooting worked. Still interested in what caused it :S

Comment: I find that at times the device gets stuck thinking (or actually) running your app when it isn't visibly doing so .. so when the debugger tries to launch it again it can't .. but it tries .. and crashes .. etc .. when I get weird crashes .. its the sign for me that I may need to reboot the device (or quit xcode)